# How to share properties and methods between Fragments in Main Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have two fragments in my `MainActivity`, I want to make the first fragment inherit a method from the second fragment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach might be to make both fragments delegate to the same object, which is more inline with the principle of preferring composition over inheritance.

Here is an example:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment(), SharedMethodsDelegate by SharedMethods {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedMethod()
    }
}

class FragmentB : Fragment(), SharedMethodsDelegate by SharedMethods {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedMethod()
    }
}


interface SharedMethodsDelegate{
    fun sharedMethod()
}

object SharedMethods : SharedMethodsDelegate {
    override fun sharedMethod() {
      print("hey")
    }
}
```

This approach would have the advantage of allowing you to use different base classes for your fragments. You could even use it to share methods between a fragment and an activity.

Comment: What if I want to inherit a property from the `baseFragment` and increment it in the `firstFragment` will it reflect in the `secondFragment`? And if not, How do I make it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can have var properties in the SharedMethodsDelegate interface

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to extract that logic into another object, and then use that object in both fragments. Unless the method is directly related to view manipulation, this would be what I suggest. It also makes the method more testable.

Answer (score 1):

Not without both Fragments sharing the same parent. you can create an instance of `Fragment` and call it `BaseFragment`, and then have both fragments that you're creating be children of `BaseFragment`. It won't be the same instance, but you'll have access to the same methods

```
        Fragment
           |
        BaseFragment <- you create this and put the methods you want to share here
            /\
           /  \
     FragmentA  FragmentB
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out